# Implementing drill down in Kibana 4

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4

Is it possible, and if so, how, to implement drill down in Kibana 4?

For example, lets say a dashboard has a pie chart which represents products.
Beneath that, there could be a table which shows component parts which are used to make products, together with supplier name, cost, availability, and other details. Clicking a product in the pie chart will filter the table to only show parts for that specific product. Selecting the supplier field would drill to another table showing the details for the supplier.

This requires that there be a multi-column table widget which would be used to display the details for each part, and that each column in the table could potentially be a link to another table.

In addition, lets say that there are three charts at the top of the dashboard. Clicking on each one should swap out the area below to display a table with a specific query and data columns relevant to the selected chart.

Is this kind of functionality abailable in Kibana?

Comment: Clicking an item in one panel will add a filter that will affect all panels.  There's no support to add or change panels.   Open/find an issue over at github.

Answer (score 2):

You can mostly achieve this type of functionality in Kibana 4.  What you'll want to do is create a search that has the fields that you want to display and save that.  Next you'll create your visualizations that have the things you want to drill down on.

Finally, create a dashboard with all of the visualizations on it, and then also add the Search (when you hit +, there's a tab that says Searches.  Choose your saved search there.

When you click on your widgets, it will start adding filters and refreshing the page, including your "search".

On the search widget that's on the dashboard, you can click on the rows and they will expand to show the fields.  Next to each field is a +/- that will let you filter to that value or exclude that value.

Comment: How should relationships be structured within the documents? i.e. parent-child, denormalized, etc., as I have read its not possible to drill down on nested relationships.  Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

I Think Kibi has this feature But again I think it is for relational database tables

Please refer to this issue
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/4439